# Firebird order by collation

Tags: sql, utf-8, firebird, firebird2.5

I am with strange problem with **Firebird 2.5**.

My database has default charset = utf8.

I have a column **p_nname** in **patienten** table:

```
CREATE TABLE PATIENTEN (
   P_NNAME       VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL COLLATE UNICODE_CI,
```

I expect collation to work everywhere. I mean in WHERE and ORDER BY clauses.

What I have is working collation in WHERE. Two queries below give me similar result and it is good.

```
select * from patienten where p_nname='adler'
select * from patienten where p_nname='ADler'
```

Problem is ORDER BY clause does not work as I expect.

This SQL works as if the column has no UNICODE_CI collation.

```
select * from patienten order by p_nname
```

To get the needed result with good sorting I have to write so:

```
select * from patienten order by p_nname collate unicode_ci
```

Is there a way to omit COLLATE flag in ORDER BY clause?

Comment: Seems like a bug. Of course the ORDER BY is supposed sort according to the column's collation.

Comment: @jarlh I mean the same but I am not a guru in Firebird.

Comment: Neither am I, have never used it. But I know the ANSI/ISO SQL standard specification well enough in this case.

Comment: What is the exact Firebird version you are using? I've just tried to reproduce the problem, but for me it is working as expected on Firebird 2.5.5.

Comment: Also, you might want to show a sample of the order and what you think it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug indeed, the [documentation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-select.html#fblangref25-dml-select-orderby) states:

> The keyword COLLATE specifies the collation order for a string column
>   if you need a collation that is different from the normal one for this
>   column. The normal collation order will be either the default one for
>   the database character set or one that has been set explicitly in the
>   column's definition.

so it should work without specifing the collate clause in ORDER BY. I suggest you file a bug report.